# Отображение картинок в WebView

Tags: android, java

Пишу вот такую красоту

```
   final String mimeType = "text/html";
   final String encoding = "utf-8";
   final String html = "<h1>Header</h1><p>Custom HTML</p><p>" +
     "<img src=\"file:///android_asset/piter.jpg>" +
     "</p>";

   WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

Оно выводит мне мою страницу, но без изображения. Что делаю не так? Помогите, пожалуйста)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый параметр в методе `loadDataWithBaseUrl()` не просто так придуман. Пишите так:

```
final String html = "<h1>Header</h1><p>Custom HTML</p><p>" + "<img src=\"piter.jpg\">" + "</p>";
...
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/ ", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

В документации методов load... написано почему так надо.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: В логах есть что-нибудь?

Comment: Все тихо, ничего нет.

Comment: Может с веб вью что-то не так?

Comment: Не знаю что я сделал, но оно каким-то макаром заработало.

Спасибо за помощь!